# Insert a List<String> to a ntext field using Linq to sql

Tags: c#, database, linq, list

I have this class:

```
public class Course
{
    public String Name { set; get; }
    public int Code { set; get; }
    public List<String> PreRequireCources = new List<String>();
}
```

and `PreRequireCources` list is filled by a listbox like this:

```
Course cu = new Course();
cu.Name = txtName.Text;
cu.Code = Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text);
cu.PreRequireCources= lstPreRequirsist.Items
    .Cast<string>().ToList();
```

and this is my course table:

[image]

If I do it like this I get an error, because `PreRequireCources` is a `List` but the database column is a `ntext`:

```
var db = new LinqDataContext();
db.Cources.InsertOnSubmit(cc);
```

So how I can save this list to my database? Are there any better ways to save this list to database for every student?
Thanks.

Comment: You will have to create a separate table for *PreRequireCources*, it could have 3 columns *Id, PreRequireCourceString and CourseCode*

Comment: Tip: never store multi-valued items in a single field. It is a nightmare to maintain later. Better use a second table `RequiredCourse` that has 2 foreign keys: one FK points to the course that HAS a required course, the other FK points to the course that IS the required course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert a list of values into a column which expects a single text value. So you can join all strings in the list into a single string

```
 cu.PreRequireCources= String.join(", ",lstPreRequirsist.Items
.Cast<string>().ToList());
```

Replace "," with your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

#### 1. Concat the strings to one string (not so good)

You could change your `Course` class to this:

```
public class Course
{
    public String Name { set; get; }
    public int Code { set; get; }
    public String PreRequireCources = string.Empty;
}
```

and fill it from the listbox like this:

```
cu.PreRequireCources = string.Join(",", lstPreRequirsist.Items.
                             Cast<string>());
```

This way you would store the courses as a `,` separated list in the `PreRequire` column.

*Note* that this is not a good way to store this kind of data. There seems to be a mxn relationship between a `Course` and the `PreRequireCources`, so...

#### 2. Create a cross table to define the mxn relationship

The better way to solve this is to create a table named something like `PreRequiredCoursesToCourses`. Let's say you have these courses

```
Code    Name        PreRequireCourses
1       Course1     Course2, Course3
2       Course2     Course3
3       Course3
```

Then remove the `PreRequireCourses` from that table and build a cross table instead:

```
CourseCode    PreRequiredCode
=============================
1             2
1             3
2             3
```

This makes your data design more efficient and flexible. Storing strings that you have to parse again to find out which courses are required is not a good idea.

If you want to request the information later, you can now use a `JOIN` to get all the courses that are pre-required for a course.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `List` as a not mapped property, and have another `string` column that gets mapped.

Then you can serialize your list, for example, using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
public class Course
{
   public String Name { set; get; }
   public int Code { set; get; }
   // Mapped to column "PreRequire"
   public String PreRequire {
      get {
         return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PreRequireCources);
      }
      set {
         PreRequireCources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(value);
      }
   }
   // Not mapped to any column
   public List<String> PreRequireCources = new List<String>();
}
```